# Camera crash in android native code(libc.so) ONLY on Samsung Snapdragon Android 11 devices

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile

This is new bug that happens only on Samsung Qualcomm Snapdragon Android 11 devices.
(Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra 5G, Samsung Galaxy Note20 Ultra 5G,Samsung Galaxy S10+..)

I have no idea how to even start debugging it - any clue will be helpful

I have reported it to Samsung developer support a month ago - but the only thing they have done is to ask me if they can close this case because there is no new data.[image]

Any other - more serious place to report android bugs?
Any idea how to fix it or debug it if I do not have a USA version?
It happens mostly when choosing high FPS like 60,120 or 240.

backtrace:

```
  #00  pc 000000000004eee4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 0000000000042b00  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+8)
  #00  pc 0000000000042444  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::dieOnMapUnmapError(bool)+56)
  #00  pc 0000000000042bbc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::map(void*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, scudo::MapPlatformData*)+184)
  #00  pc 0000000000046554  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::MapAllocator<scudo::MapAllocatorCache<256u, 256u, 33554432ul, 0, 1000> >::allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long*, bool)+408)
  #00  pc 00000000000446ec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::allocate(unsigned long, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, bool)+1196)
  #00  pc 00000000000441c0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo_calloc+48)
  #00  pc 000000000003badc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (calloc+52)
  #00  pc 0000000000006fb8  /system/lib64/libcamera_metadata.so (allocate_camera_metadata+60)
  #00  pc 000000000005696c  /system/lib64/libcamera_client.so (android::CameraMetadata::resizeIfNeeded(unsigned long, unsigned long)+144)
  #00  pc 0000000000056e00  /system/lib64/libcamera_client.so (android::CameraMetadata::updateImpl(unsigned int, void const*, unsigned long)+312)
  #00  pc 0000000000153d34  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (CameraMetadata_writeValues(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, int, _jbyteArray*, long)+848)
  #00  pc 000000000024bf88  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+200)
  #00  pc 000000000200b630  /memfd:jit-cache (android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraMetadataNative.setBase+752)
  #00  pc 0000000002006a40  /memfd:jit-cache (android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraMetadataNative.set+336)
  #00  pc 0000000002003720  /memfd:jit-cache (android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onResultReceived+544)
  #00  pc 0000000002002bc8  /memfd:jit-cache (android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceCallbacks$Stub.onTransact+856)
  #00  pc 000000000074aaec  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal+844)
  #00  pc 000000000074a678  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.execTransact+296)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
  #00  pc 00000000005309a8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #00  pc 0000000000531f44  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+448)
  #00  pc 0000000000532128  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92)
  #00  pc 000000000038c958  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallBooleanMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+660)
  #00  pc 000000000009eaa8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallBooleanMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124)
  #00  pc 000000000012cf8c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaBBinder::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+160)
  #00  pc 000000000004a834  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+232)
  #00  pc 0000000000053ab4  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+700)
  #00  pc 0000000000053748  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+156)
  #00  pc 0000000000054304  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+116)
  #00  pc 000000000007cc00  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #00  pc 000000000001553c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+320)
  #00  pc 00000000000a48a8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+144)
  #00  pc 0000000000014db0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+408)
  #00  pc 00000000000b61f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050e24  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```